# Javascript to execute automatically if cookie exists

Tags: javascript, function, cookies, automation, policy

I am trying to make a cookie policy notification popup and it works exactly how I want it to, and creates a cookie. However, as I am new to javascript (plus coding of any sort) I do not know how to have another script which searches for the cookie 'STLCSD', and if it exists, run the 'hideDiv' function.

I would like to avoid using anything other than HTML, CSS and JS, simply because the platform this establishment uses does not support anything else.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Just ask for any further details

```
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 
function hideDiv() { 
if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.height= '0px'; 
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.fontSize= '0px'; 
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.color= '#cddfea';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.top= '-10px';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.backgroundColor= '#cddfea';
document.getElementById('topbar').style.height= '1px';


} 
else { 
if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
document.hideShow.height= '0px'; 
document.hideShow.fontSize= '0px';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.color= '#cddfea';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.top= '-10px';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.backgroundColor= '#cddfea';
document.getElementById('topbar').style.height= '1px';


} 
else { // IE 4 
document.all.hideShow.style.height= '0px'; 
document.all.hideShow.style.fontSize= '0px'; 
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.top= '-10px';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.color= '#cddfea';
document.getElementById('hideShow').style.backgroundColor= '#cddfea';
document.getElementById('topbar').style.height= '1px';


} 
} 
} 

function cookiepolicy(){
   days=50; // number of days to keep the cookie
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   document.cookie = 'cookieName=STLCSD; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
}


</script> 

<style>
#hideShow{
color:white;
font-family:Gill Sans MT;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:20px;
height:35px;
width:100%;
transition:.3s;
background-color:#0e589e;
margin:0px;
padding:3px;
top:0px;
position:absolute;
}

#hideshow a:link{
color:#0e589e;
font-style:bold;
background-color:#cddfea;
padding-left:9px;
padding-right:9px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0px;
right:40px;
position:absolute;
}

#topbar{
color:white;
font-family:Gill Sans MT;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:20px;
height:35px;
width:100%;
transition:.3s;
background-color:#cddfea;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
top:0px;

}


</style>
<div id="topbar">
</div>
<div id="hideShow" ..etc> 
<b>Cookie Policy</b>
This site uses cookies to store information on your computer.
<a href="javascript:hideDiv()" onclick="cookiepolicy()">Accept</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: It's nice that you care for IE4 and Netscape 4 users :)

Comment: Its a school website so we kinda have to try and accommodate for parents

Answer (score 2):

I used a function like this:

```
function readCookie(cookieName)
{
  if(document.cookie.length > 0)
  {
    var begin = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName + "=");
    if(begin != -1) {
        begin = begin + cookieName.length + 1;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";",begin);
        if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(begin,end));
    } else {
       return "";
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

after that, you can use something like:

```
if(readCookie("STLCSD") == "true") { hideDiv(); }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your quick answer :) unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working for me :(

Comment: @RJcreatives, try to dump `readCookie("STLCSD")` result. what is its output?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: cookieName is not defined index.phtml?d=603591&preview=1&t=1385647072:596
readCookie index.phtml?d=603591&preview=1&t=1385647072:596
(anonymous function)

This is the only error in the console

Comment: After some tweaking, this is the new error -
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string index.phtml?d=603591&preview=1&t=1385647072:592
Uncaught ReferenceError: cookiepolicy is not defined index.phtml?d=603591&preview=1&t=1385647072:667
onclick index.phtml?d=603591&preview=1&t=1385647072:667
Uncaught ReferenceError: hideDiv is not defined index.phtml?d=603591&preview=1&t=1385647072:1
(anonymous function)

Comment: from your error it seems you didn't copy&paste the answer (which is working) as written; did you changed the code from @rikpg answer somehow?

Comment: im using chrome and ie9

Comment: from your errors, it seems there's a syntax error somewhere: even your functions are not defined anymore (`hideDiv is not defined`)